# using sed to replace a line with back slashes in a shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, ssh, sed

I am trying to replace the bottom one of these 2 lines with sed in a file.

```
    <rule>out_prefix=orderid ^1\\d\+ updatemtnotif/</rule>\n\
    <rule>out_prefix=orderid ^2\\d\+ updatemtnotif/</rule>\n\
```

And the following command seems to do that when executed as a command at the bash prompt

```
sed -i 's@out_prefix=orderid ^2\\\\d\\+ updatemtnotif/@out_prefix=orderid ^2\\\\d\\+ updatemtnotif_fr/@g' /opt/temp/rules.txt
```

however, when I try to execute the same command remotely over ssh using here documents, the command fails to modify the file. 
I think this is probably an escaping issue, but I have had no luck trying to modify the command in numerous ways. Can any one tell me what should I do to get it working over ssh? Thanks in advance!

to clarify,

```
input: <rule>out_prefix=orderid ^2\\d\+ updatemtnotif/</rule>\n\
output: <rule>out_prefix=orderid ^2\\d\+ updatemtnotif_fr/</rule>\n\
```

Comment: What's your exact input and expected output?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I have modified the question with expected input and output

Comment: nescoffe 3 for (in) 1 , for backslashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it with `ssh` and heredoc like this:

```
ssh -t -t user@localhost<<'EOF'
sed 's~out_prefix=orderid ^2\\\\d\\+ updatemtnotif/~out_prefix=orderid ^2\\\\d\\+ updatemtnotif_fr/~' ~/path/to/file
exit
EOF
```

**PS:** It is important to **quote** the `'EOF'` as shown.

Comment: Hey @anubhava , didn't know about quoting the 'EOF'. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. had to escape the backslashes in the command I used inside the shell script.

```
 's@out_prefix=orderid ^2\\\\\\\\d\\\\+ updatemtnotif/@out_prefix=orderid ^2\\\\\\\\d\\\\+ updatemtnotif_fr/@g' /opt/temp/rules.txt
```

That's a whole lot of backslashes but it did the trick.